# Rational functions and power series

Tags: cv.complex-variables, power-series

Let $P(z)/Q(z)$ be a rational function ($\mathbf{C}$ coefficients) and assume that its Taylor series $\alpha(z)=\sum_{n\geq 0} a_n z^n$ around $z=0$ has radius of convergence $1$. Consider the power series $|\alpha|(z)=\sum_{n\geq 0}|a_n|z^n$, which also has radius of convergence $1$. Is $|\alpha|(z)$ a rational function?

Comment: I suppose the generating function of $a_n=\cos nt$ is rational while the generating function of $|\cos nt|$ is not, for irrational $t$.

Comment: @AlexandreEremenko Of course you mean irrational multiples of $\pi$.

Comment: @Robert Israel: yes, this is what I mean.

Comment: Note that $\sum_n |a_n|^2 z^n$ is always a rational function when $\sum_n a_n z^n$ is a  Laurent expansion of a rational function. @AlexandreEremenko

Comment: And more generally if $\sum_{n} a_n z^n$ and $\sum_{n} b_n z^n$ are rational functions, so is $\sum_n a_n b_n z^n$.  But  $\sum_n |a_n| z^n$ is not of this form.

Comment: Just to provide some context for this question. Under the hypothesis for the radius of convergence and the extra requirement that all $a_n$ are integers, a theorem of Fritz Carlson says that $\alpha(z)$ is either rational or it has the circle as a cut. I suspect that even in this this situation there are examples for which $\alpha$ is rational and $|\alpha|$ has the circle as a cut, but I am unable to find an explicit one.